# Running a main function for several objects

Tags: python

I have a kind of tricky problem here. Basically what I want to do is have a tamaguchi-like program, where people get to choose what the tamaguchi does and it either increases in size or decreases. This works great for there's only one tamaguchi! But it should be possible to create and manage several tamaguchis simultaneously. I run into big problems when I try this though. Basically this is how I've been thinking so far:

```
class Tamaguchi(object):
    def __init__(self,name,size=1):
        self.name=name
        self.size=size

    def increasesize(self):
        self.size+=1
        GoodBadChange.config(text="Good job. You increased in size!")

    def decreasesize(self):
        self.size-=1
        GoodBadChange.config(text="Bad job. You decreased in size!")

def main():
    print(name)
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    global root
    root.title("Tamaguchi-spelet")
    root.geometry("900x900")
    getLists()
    getPhotos()
    Picture = tkinter.Label(root, image=normal)
    Picture.pack()
    global Picture
    ScoreBoard = tkinter.Label(root, text="Score " + str(tamaguchin.size), font=('Helvetica', 15))
    ScoreBoard.pack()
    global ScoreBoard
    GoodBadChange = tkinter.Label(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 12))
    GoodBadChange.pack()
    global GoodBadChange
    LatestAction = tkinter.Label(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 12))
    LatestAction.pack()
    global LatestAction
    app = Application(root)
    app.pack()
    updateDisplay()
    LatestAction.config(text="Hello and welcome to the tamaguchi game!\nThe tamaguchi  starts the day with the size "+str(tamaguchin.size)+"!\nThe tamaguchi starts the day off with the last three actions of "+lista[0]+"-"+lista[1]+"-"+lista[2]+"\n")
    root.mainloop()

tamaguchi_list=[]
amount=int(input("Number of tamaguchis in your farm: "))
for i in range(amount):
    name = input("What do you want to name your tamaguchis?: ")
    tamaguchi_name = Tamaguchi(name)
    tamaguchi_list.append(tamaguchi_name)

for tamaguchis in tamaguchi_list:
    main()

for tamaguchis in tamaguchi_list:
    print(name,"reached a size of ",name.size,"!")
```

Sorry it's a bit long, I've still shortened off the parts that aren't relevant. But I was thinking, we create a list with all the tamaguchis in them, and then we just run the main function for each tamaguchi in the tamaguchi-list. That way, for example "erik" gets one score, and "mary" another, and this should then be written in the end. However, this does not seem to work, as you can see I write "print(name)" in the beginning of the main function just to see that it actually goes through all the names in the list, but in fact it just prints the same name over and over again. I have no idea why it doesn't go through all names.

Another problem is the fact I have written in the main function stuff like `str(tamaguchin.size)` when I want to show the size of the tamaguchi, but this was because when I only had one tamaguchi I just created it in the beginning and I could just refer to that in the rest of the program (tamaguchin=Tamaguchi('SomeName') is what I used to have!) Can this be solved?

Thanks a lot for any help, I'm really stuck with this.

edit: Perhaps it's unclear since I don't show all of the code. I thought it might just be too long, but perhaps it's better to understand what I mean! [I uploaded it here!](https://gist.github.com/imfromsweden/8172070)

Comment: Your list probably contains reference to the same object, so no wonder all the names are the same because they are, in fact, the same.

Comment: From where does `main` get inputs like `name` and, more importantly, `tamaguchin`?

Comment: the fact that the main function references to stuff like "tamaguchin" is a relic from the program only worked for one tamaguchi. Back then I just created a tamaguchi in the begining which got the object name "tamaguchin". From there it was easy to just reference to that all the time. I know it needs to be changed, I just don't know how or to what, if I want to have several tamaguchis :o

name comes from input, "name = input("What do you want to name your tamaguchis?")

Comment: Here's the answer to your problem, most likely: you've got a reference `tamaguchin` defined somewhere which refers to only one tamaguchi, hence you always get its name printed. Why not have a tamaguchi being an input to `main`? Otherwise this whole for `tamaguchis in tamaguchi_list:` block makes **no sense at all** since you don't actually loop over the tamaguchis, i.e. you do nothing to each one of them... Do you get your problem?

Comment: Right, yeah I kind of understand, but not quite ;) How do you mean I should structure main then? Like have a question in the begining of main, like name = input("what u want it to be called?"), and when the loop ends, they get the question if they want to start the mainloop all over again (at which point they get to create a new tamaguchi, with a new name). Is this how you mean? :) I updated OP btw, so maybe you can get a better understanding of the problem :)

Comment: From a fellow swede: Looking at your full code link...never, ever use anything except english for variable names, functions, etc. English is the "lingua-franca" of programming, and if you use it your chances of getting help (and a job!) will increase. You obviously have no problem with english, so doing the programming in english as well should not give you a hard time. Bara som ett tips :)

Comment: @user3122480 Nope, I mean keep everything the same just pass a reference to the object. E.g.
`lst=[1,2,3];
for thing in lst:
    someFunction( thing )` where `someFunction` does something to a `thing`.

Comment: Thanks, will keep in mind for the future! :)

Comment: isn't that what I am doing? :o The list contains all the tamaguchis, and for ta,aguchi in tamaguchilist: main(), which affects the tamaguchi (the main function changes it's size)

Answer (score 0):

This chapter describes a game in which the player causes a creature to "increase in size" due to an event in the game: http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter6.html

Read through the game design and similar to increasing the size you can decrease the size of the creature.

In order to manage multiple creatures read this chapter: http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter8.html

Answer (score -1):

I need you to be more specific in which lines of your code your error is occurring to properly answer this question. That being said, however, I would recommend using a more efficient structure to manage your tamaguchins.

What I understood you describing was 'tamaguchi does something' then 'tamaguchi grows or shrinks'.

Try something like this using a dictionary:

```
tamaguchins = {"ralph":10, "george":5, "chester":2}

def size_modify(tamaguchin, plus_minus, tamaguchins):
    tamaguchins[tamaguchin] += plus_minus
    return tamaguchins
```

Call it like this:

```
tamaguchins = size_modify("ralph", -1, tamaguchins)
```

Or like this:

```
tamaguchins = size_modify("george", 1, tamaguchins)
```

Or however you like, just remember that in this case you must always precede the calling of the function with 'tamaguchins =' and your third argument must always be tamaguchins.

Cheers

Comment: Will this work for all names though? I don't want it only to work for "george", it should work for any names the user puts in. I'm always a bit afraid of hard-coding stuff like that :p I think using a dictionary might be clever though, since I can then call for the function dictionary["size"] for example if that's what I want to change. I updated the OP btw so it includes the entire code.

Comment: `just remember that in this case you must always precede the calling of the function with tamaguchins =`  This is just plain wrong. `dict` objects are mutable, so there is no need to return the new dict. It is changed in place.

Comment: Hannes is correct it is not imperative that the dictionary be returned  however I would still recommend the function be structured and called in this way. This simply because it makes the function more flexible in that the opperation can be performed on lists or dictionaries.

Comment: user3122480, the function as is works with any of the aforementioned names. You will however of course have to append each new tamaguchi into the tamaguchis list, then you can just target whichever tamaguchi with the same index syntax: size_modify("name", 1/-1, tamaguchis)